# Removing file type from attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, string, remove

I imported a shapefile that contains track plots of SGY files into QGIS, and  I would like to remove *'.sgy'* from the file names in the attribute table.

In the image, I've highlighted the section of the filename that I would like to delete in bulk

[image: example]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

Open "Field Calculator", check "Update existing field", select "NAME" field and use the following expression.

```
substr("NAME", 0, -4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, one can use the following expression:

```
regexp_substr("name",'([^.]+)')
```

it includes the [`regexp_substr()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-substr) function.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative using the [`file_suffix()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#file-suffix) function. This expression concatenates a `.` with the file suffix and replaces it with an empty string.

```
replace("NAME", '.' || file_suffix("NAME"), '')
```

---

QGIS 3.24.0

Comment: very clever and neat!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@Matt solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/429031/99589), there is also a special function called [`base_file_name()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#base-file-name):

```
base_file_name("name")
```

However, for a filename with multiple `.` (such as `my_compressed_file.tar.gz`) this only removes the last file extension (`.gz`). Whereas [`file_suffix()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#file-suffix) finds `tar.gz`.

Comment: Looks like I made my edit to include `base_file_name` at the same time you posted this answer! Would you like to poach my sentence about multiple `.`, and I can remove it from my answer?

Comment: If you don’t mind I can, I just do not know what is the most honest way in this case :)